# How to Restart explorer.exe Remotely?

Tags: remote, windows-explorer

I'm having big troubles with a remote server that for some reason explorer.exe crashed and, although I didn't lose remote desktop connectivity, I can't do anything. Is there a way of restarting explorer without rebooting the server?

I appreciate ANY suggestions!!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Explorer runs on a per-user basis. Can you log in under a different account that isn't already logged in?

Edit: Also, if your remote desktop session is still active, CTRL + ALT + END should have the same effect as a CTRL + ALT + DEL on the remote system. That might get you the Task Manager up, in which case you can kill/restart explorer.exe as required.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I can log in even with the same user but not using the console. Right now there are applications running in the console.

Comment: If you can log in, you can remotely log off another user via the Task Manager.

Comment: Well, that'd do it. Was hoping to actually have some sort of script to restart it remotely, but thanks anyway!

Comment: If you want to keep the user logged in, can you connect to the console session using mstsc /admin (or mstsc /console if you're using XP/2003) and then do a CTRL+ALT+END from there?

Comment: Wow... years of Windows sysadmining, and yet I didn't know about CTRL-ALT-END. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Massimo You may also enjoy [Remote Desktop Tips and Tricks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/remote-desktop-tips-and-tricks.html) via SE's own `^w` ex Jeff Atwood.

Comment: 1. CTRL+ALT+DEL
2. Click Task Manager
3. Click File
4. New Task Run
5. Type "explorer"
6. OK - All done

Comment: this answer saved my life

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> is a keyboard shortcut for launching the Task Manager. It has "File->New Task..." which is basically a Run dialog that you'd normally get with <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, which you can use to restart Explorer by entering "explorer" or "explorer.exe". I have used this shortcut numerous times when explorer has crashed and not restarted.

This shortcut is handy whether or not you are on remote desktop, but it definitely comes across regular remote desktop sessions (whereas <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> does not) and is extra useful in that case.

REMEMBER: if you're in remote desktop, reconnect and check the option the "Apply Windows Key combinations" = On the remote computer for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

If the explorer.exe is not killed yet, kill it in the task manager.

Hit windows+R for the run dialog, then enter `explorer.exe`, and hit ok. The explorer.exe should be started again, and you be good to go (on). Alternatively, to start the process, you can use the taskmanagers *New Task…* button from the Applications tab, which opens a run dialog as well (just renamed).

Comment: Thank you Kissaki, but I can't do that since explorer crashed, meaning no desktop, no start bar, nothing. This is a remote computer and I'm connecting to it through remote desktop, which means I can't type the Windows key.

Comment: Eh? Remote desktop allows you to press the windows key. At least mine does. :) Captures it within the remote machine (/sends the keypress to the remote machine).

Comment: I may have missed to mention that I'm using a remote desktop over Citrix